# accessing Maildir locally with Mutt and remotely over IMAP simultaneously

Tags: postfix, mutt, imap, dovecot, maildir

I have `Postfix` + `Maildir` + `Dovecot` + `IMAP` on my mailserver. I am accessing my mailbox remotely over `IMAP` with one or more clients (Thunderbird). Additionally, on the server I have mutt configured for local (`Maildir`) access.

When I am connected over `IMAP` with Thunderbird, and simultaneously start `mutt` locally on the server, `Mutt` seems to be confused. When I move a message in Thunderbird (over `IMAP`), `Mutt` notices something has changed and reports:

```
Mailbox was externally modified.  Flags may be wrong
```

The problem seems to be one-sided. When I manipulate a message in `Mutt`, Thunderbird registers the change and has no problem with it.

**Thus my question:**

How can I make remote `IMAP` client and local `Mutt` client acccess `Maildir` without any conflicts/data corruption/errors?

**Important:**

I am looking for a solution where the `Mutt` access is local. For reasons beyond this discussion, I don't want `Mutt` to access the Maildir over `IMAP.`

**Sidenote:**

I don't understand why `Mutt` complains that mailbox was externally modified. After all, Postfix also modifies the mailbox when it delivers new emails.

Comment: FYI: Mutt does the same thing when its connected over IMAP and a different IMAP client modifies the mailbox.

Answer (score 2):

Maildir store some data in the message filename. That data include message ID, sizes (with and w/o newlines) and flags. When unread message is opened, it is moved from `new` to `cur` and its name changes from

```
1406379300.M375059P35208.R93M.lan,S=679,W=699
```

to

```
1406379300.M375059P35208.R93M.lan,S=679,W=699:2,S
```

IMAP server can track that changes cause it use maildir's index file to access certain message. When `mutt` access messages directly from filesystem collisions are unavoidable.

Comment: But as @derobert says, mutt still does the same thing when using IMAP.

Comment: But you has wrote that `mutt` access maildir locally and IMAP access is inappropriate?

Answer (score 1):

Mutt does not "complain" about mailbox externally modified, it merely informs the user about changes resulting in simultaneous access to the same mailbox. Some cached flags might be out of sync, but generally it is not a problem. You can always reopen the mailbox to reread it. A new mail is announced differently, so this message is not seen in this situation.

Similar happens also when opening the mailbox via another ssh session or network mount, it is not IMAP specific.

There is no conflict/data corruption/error. Both mbox and maildir formats are designed for simultaneous access.